# ethe App. crashs after adding google maps tag in the xml file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

After adding the following lines to the .xml file, the App crashs.

And how to get the map api key??

Any suggestions.

.xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="Your Maps API Key"
    android:clickable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat:

```
03-03 19:22:31.978: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-03 19:22:31.978: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-03 19:22:31.978: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 19:22:31.978: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-03 19:22:31.978: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-03 19:22:31.978: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 19:22:31.978: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-03 19:22:31.978: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-03 19:22:31.978: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-03 19:22:31.978: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 19:22:31.978: E/AndroidRuntime(871): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider==null
03-03 19:22:31.978: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:441)
03-03 19:22:31.978: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at com.androidbook.LocationsAPIDemo.LocationsAPIDemoActivity.onResume(LocationsAPIDemoActivity.java:54)
03-03 19:22:31.978: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
03-03 19:22:31.978: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
03-03 19:22:31.978: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
03-03 19:22:31.978: E/AndroidRuntime(871):  ... 12 more
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidbook.LocationsAPIDemo/com.androidbook.LocationsAPIDemo.LocationsAPIDemoActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at com.androidbook.LocationsAPIDemo.LocationsAPIDemoActivity.onCreate(LocationsAPIDemoActivity.java:27)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     ... 11 more
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     ... 22 more
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:291)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:264)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:247)
03-03 20:16:50.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1012):     ... 25 more
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidbook.LocationsAPIDemo/com.androidbook.LocationsAPIDemo.LocationsAPIDemoActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at com.androidbook.LocationsAPIDemo.LocationsAPIDemoActivity.onCreate(LocationsAPIDemoActivity.java:27)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     ... 11 more
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     ... 22 more
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:291)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:264)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:247)
03-03 20:18:33.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):     ... 25 more
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidbook.LocationsAPIDemo/com.androidbook.LocationsAPIDemo.LocationsAPIDemoActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at com.androidbook.LocationsAPIDemo.LocationsAPIDemoActivity.onCreate(LocationsAPIDemoActivity.java:27)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     ... 11 more
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     ... 22 more
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:291)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:264)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:247)
03-03 20:29:14.449: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     ... 25 more
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidbook.LocationsAPIDemo/com.androidbook.LocationsAPIDemo.LocationsAPIDemoActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at com.androidbook.LocationsAPIDemo.LocationsAPIDemoActivity.onCreate(LocationsAPIDemoActivity.java:27)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     ... 11 more
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     ... 22 more
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:291)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:264)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:247)
03-03 20:30:06.300: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):     ... 25 more
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidbook.LocationsAPIDemo/com.androidbook.LocationsAPIDemo.LocationsAPIDemoActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at com.androidbook.LocationsAPIDemo.LocationsAPIDemoActivity.onCreate(LocationsAPIDemoActivity.java:27)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     ... 11 more
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     ... 22 more
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:291)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:264)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:247)
03-03 21:05:44.128: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     ... 25 more
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidbook.LocationsAPIDemo/com.androidbook.LocationsAPIDemo.LocationsAPIDemoActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at com.androidbook.LocationsAPIDemo.LocationsAPIDemoActivity.onCreate(LocationsAPIDemoActivity.java:27)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     ... 11 more
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     ... 22 more
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:291)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:264)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:247)
03-03 23:02:31.318: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted the LogCat output, so it's hard to know why it is crashing, but it's probably because you've left the comment in there for the Maps key.

Here's a tutorial explaining how to get a (free) Google Maps API key, to insert into your app. Note that you generally need TWO. One is for your app when it's in debug mode (using the debug signing key). the other is for when you use a production version of the app (signed with a production signing key).

http://remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a35/Android-How-To-Set-Up-an-API-Key-for-Google-Maps.html